# How Power on laptop automatically?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, laptop

hello everyone Laptop name=>HP Elitebook pro 6460b
my younger brother power button not working when system is shut down then not working starting again.
Is any possibility in ubuntu 20.04 when User open the laptop automatically start?
I wish I do work without using power button any one know please share with me thanks

Comment: I suspect that needs to be done through a hardware/firmware solution, as if the machine is off, Ubuntu cannot by definition be running, so you need a hardware/firmware option to boot your machine, which is off-topic as I read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic (not a Ubuntu issue, but issue related to your HP device)

Comment: Hardware issues can not be solved through software. "Is any possibility in ubuntu 20.04 when User open the laptop automatically start?" No. There is no Ubuntu active when the system is turned off so no way for an OS to start something. The solution is to fix the power button.  Or never turn it off and use hibernation. Any key can be used to activate from hibernation.

Comment: You can look in the BIOS. There may be an option to power on with another key,.  I do this on Desktops all the time to save me bending over. Look in the bios for Wake on Lan.  Maybe you can do a suspend and then wake from phone or other computer. FIRST look at the bios for other options.